# Is it a library bug in a functional language when a function with the same name but for different collections produces different side effects?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, evaluation, scala-streams

I'm using Scala 2.13.1 and evaluate my examples in a worksheet.

At first, I define two functions that return the range of *a* to (*z*-1) as a stream or respectively a lazy list.

```
def streamRange(a: Int, z: Int): Stream[Int] = {
  print(a + " ")
  if (a >= z) Stream.empty else a #:: streamRange(a + 1, z)
}

def lazyListRange(a: Int, z: Int): LazyList[Int] = {
  print(a + " ")
  if (a >= z) LazyList.empty else a #:: lazyListRange(a + 1, z)
}
```

Then I call both functions, take a Stream/LazyList of 3 elements and convert them to List:

```
streamRange(1, 10).take(3).toList    // prints 1 2 3
lazyListRange(1, 10).take(3).toList  // prints 1 2 3 4
```

Here I do the same again:

```
val stream1 = streamRange(1, 10)     // prints 1
val stream2 = stream1.take(3)
stream2.toList                       // prints 2 3

val lazyList1 = lazyListRange(1,10)  // prints 1
val lazyList2 = lazyList1.take(3)
lazyList2.toList                     // prints 2 3 4
```

The 1 is printed because the function is visited and the print statement is at the start. No surprise.

But I don't understand why the additional 4 is printed for the lazy list and not for the stream.

My assumption is that at the point where 3 is to be concatenated with the next function call, the LazyList version visits the function, whereas in the Stream version the function is not visited. Otherwise the 4 would not have been printed.

It seems like unintended behaviour, at least it is unexpected. But would this difference in side effects be considered a bug or just a detailed difference in the evaluation of Stream and LazyList.

Comment: **LazyList** evaluates both its head an tail, so computing the third element evaluated that 4 tail. In any case, neither of those types should be mixed with side effects. Consider using **fs2**, **zstream**, **monix** or **akka streams**.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the difference in evaluation and also for the comment on side effects. My thoughts now about the example: The tail you mention is an expression and has a value. This expression is in this case strictly evaluated and during this evaluation side effects like the print call can occur. Now, what about the value of tail, the result of evaluation of tail. We arrive at (a #:: nextTail). And #:: returns a LazyList where evaluation of both head and tail is deferred. This is the value of tail, a LazyList the contents of which have not been computed yet.

Comment: And if the head of this LazyList is accessed, then again both head and tail will be evaluated. Different from the Stream, where the head can be accessed without evaluating the tail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Stream` implements `#::` using [`Deferer`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/d6bb22a688528bec619ae18fa964e42853e08807/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.scala#L435):

```
  implicit def toDeferrer[A](l: => Stream[A]): Deferrer[A] = new Deferrer[A](() => l)

  final class Deferrer[A] private[Stream] (private val l: () => Stream[A]) extends AnyVal {
    /** Construct a Stream consisting of a given first element followed by elements
      *  from another Stream.
      */
    def #:: [B >: A](elem: B): Stream[B] = new Cons(elem, l())
    /** Construct a Stream consisting of the concatenation of the given Stream and
      *  another Stream.
      */
    def #:::[B >: A](prefix: Stream[B]): Stream[B] = prefix lazyAppendedAll l()
  }
```

where `Cons`:

```
final class Cons[A](override val head: A, tl: => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A] {
```

Whereas `LazyList` implements `#::` with its own [`Deferer`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/c74434ffa515531e3279fa81ba5025dbf2ff1322/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/LazyList.scala#L1114):

```
  implicit def toDeferrer[A](l: => LazyList[A]): Deferrer[A] = new Deferrer[A](() => l)

  final class Deferrer[A] private[LazyList] (private val l: () => LazyList[A]) extends AnyVal {
    /** Construct a LazyList consisting of a given first element followed by elements
      *  from another LazyList.
      */
    def #:: [B >: A](elem: => B): LazyList[B] = newLL(sCons(elem, l()))
    /** Construct a LazyList consisting of the concatenation of the given LazyList and
      *  another LazyList.
      */
    def #:::[B >: A](prefix: LazyList[B]): LazyList[B] = prefix lazyAppendedAll l()
  }
```

where `sCons`:

```
@inline private def sCons[A](hd: A, tl: LazyList[A]): State[A] = new State.Cons[A](hd, tl)
```

and `Cons`:

```
final class Cons[A](val head: A, val tail: LazyList[A]) extends State[A]
```

It means that on the very definition level:

- `Steam` lazily evaluates it tail's **creation**
- `LazyList` lazily evaluates its tail's **content**

Difference is noticeable among other in side-effects... which neither of these if made for.

If you want to handle potentially infinite sequences of impore computations, use a proper streaming library: Akka Streams, FS2, ZIO Streams. Build-in streams/lazy list are made for pure computations and if you step into impure directory you should assume that no guarantees regarding side effects are provided.

Comment: Thank you, this answer was really helpful, also the comments on impure computations and streaming libraries.

Comment: So, #:: of Stream returns a Cons object (of type Stream) where elem is strictly evaluated and the tail "l()" is lazily evaluated. LazyLists: Other than in Cons of Stream, the tail is not a by-name parameter in Cons of LazyList. If the Cons is constructed, both head and tail are evaluated. So, in the evaluation of tail there could occur side-effects like printing 4 before a value (the lazy list tail) is returned, and because the tail in Stream's Cons is evaluated by-name, side-effects from tail evaluation cannot occur yet. That's as far as I got so far in my understanding of the example.

Comment: Internals are implementation detail. The bottom line is that If you _really_ have to do impure computations with Stream/LazyList (any effect really) do them _inside_ using some build-in functions, but not before calculating creating tail. Think of `Future` - if you do `Future { println }` it works as expected but if you did `{ println; Future.succesful }` things wouldn't the way you want. E.g. with `LazyList` I would use `LazyList.from(1).map { i => println(i + " "); i }` - side effect would happen at the moment it is needed to calculate the current value not before it.

Comment: Thank you, this was also very helpful for me. In this sense, if I write `{print(a + " "); a} #:: lazyListRange(a + 1, z)` in my example function, then a number only gets printed the moment when it is also evaluated as head. Which is what I intended to print.